# log4j2 Unable to create file

Tags: log4j2

I'm trying to write error to log file in my Java desktop app but it's not working.

The error is:

> 2018-11-02 21:10:27,975 AWT-EventQueue-0 ERROR Unable to create file
>   C:UsersNhanDesktopPRJ311JDBCsrc hanloggerlogging.log
>   java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label
>   syntax is incorrect

Here is my configuration:

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig
property.filename = C:\Users\Nhan\Desktop\PRJ311\JDBC
filters = threshold
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug
appenders = rolling
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -  %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20
loggers = rolling
logger.rolling.name = nhan.views
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Answer (score 0):

A backslash has a special meaning in a properties file per [the Java Properties class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-). You need to escape your backslashes by adding another backslash to each of them:

```
 C:\\Users\\Nhan\\Desktop\\PRJ311\\JDBC
```

Comment: I tried what you said and there is no error but there is nothing written in the log file

Comment: When I run your exact configuration it generates the file "JDBC" in the folder "PRJ311" and the logs are there. If this is not happening for you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because there is not enough information in your question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Now it creates new log every error instead of writing in 1 file. How can I fix it?